# What does the 'defaults' mount option mean for NTFS drives/partitions?

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

For EXT4 drives the [*defaults*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab) option in /etc/fstab translates to:

```
rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async
```

I want to know what the *defaults* option transaltes into for NTFS drives. It is not covered in the [NTFS-3G manual](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/) and not in the [Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man mount`, the `defaults` option is filesystem-independent.

> **FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS**
>
> Some of these options are only useful when they appear in the /etc/fstab file.
>
> Some of these options could be enabled or disabled by default in the system kernel. To check the current setting see the options in /proc/mounts.
>
> The following options apply to any filesystem that is being mounted (but not every filesystem actually honors them - e.g., the sync option today has effect only for ext2, ext3, fat, vfat and ufs):
>
> [...]
>
> **defaults**
>
> Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.

Comment: Glad I could help. And to be honest, `man mount`, `/defaults` doesn't take all that long. ;)

Comment: Yes, I did do `man mount.ntfs` but I should have looked in `man mount` obviously...